# How can pre-commit checks fail locally but pass on a CI server?

Tags: pre-commit.com

I have a clean working tree of a branch on my development machine. If I run `pre-commit run --all-files` my formatter hooks fail, reformatting some files. My CI server (Atlassian Bamboo) also runs `pre-commit run --all-files` on the same branch, but the hooks pass, which is unexpected. What can I check to figure out why?

As an example, I added the following line to a Python file:

```py
unused = 1+1
```

I have a black hook for formatting and a ruff hook for linting. Locally the output is:

```
black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- files were modified by this hook

reformatted tasks/tool.py

All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted, 1878 files left unchanged.

ruff.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: ruff
- exit code: 1

tasks/tool.py:76:5: F841 [*] Local variable `unused` is assigned to but never used
Found 1 error.
[*] 1 potentially fixable with the --fix option.
```

This is as expected -- black will reformat the line as `unused = 1 + 1` (spaces around the plus operator) and ruff rightly identifies that `unused` is unused.

On the CI server, however, the output is:

```
black....................................................................Passed
ruff.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: ruff
- exit code: 1

tasks/tool.py:76:5: F841 [*] Local variable `unused` is assigned to but never used
Found 1 error.
[*] 1 potentially fixable with the --fix option.
```

The unexpected pass is not unique to black. I also have hooks for mdformat and clang-format that also fail locally and pass unexpectedly on the CI server.

Things I've tried:

- Added a call to `pre-commit --version` in both places to be sure they're the same (3.3.3)
- Added a call to `pre-commit clean` in both places to be sure there's not some weird caching issue for hooks
- Added the identity hook to be sure files aren't being filtered out differently somehow

What other things can I do to track this down?

Here is my (trimmed-down but hopefully still valid/representative) pre-commit-config.yaml:

```yaml
default_language_version:
    python: python3.10

exclude: >
    (?x)^(
        acceptance/.*|
        build/.*|
        deploy/.*
    )$

repos:

-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/docformatter
    rev: v1.1
    hooks:
        -   id: docformatter
            alias: reformat-docs
            types: [python]
            args:
                - --in-place

-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: "23.3.0"
    hooks:
        -   id: black
            alias: reformat
            types: [python]

-   repo: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-pre-commit
    rev: v0.0.292
    hooks:
        - id: ruff
          alias: lint
          types: [python]

-   repo: https://github.com/executablebooks/mdformat
    rev: "0.7.16"
    hooks:
    -   id: mdformat
        description: Auto-format Markdown files.
        args: [--wrap=88, --number]
        additional_dependencies:
        - mdformat-gfm==0.3.5
        - mdformat-tables==0.4.1
        - mdformat-black==0.1.1
        - linkify-it-py==2.0.2

-   repo: https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint.git
    rev: v1.29.0
    hooks:
        -   id: yamllint
            description: This hook runs yamllint.
            entry: yamllint
            language: python
            types: [file, yaml]
            args:
                - -c
                - yamllint-config.yml
                - --no-warnings

-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-clang-format
    rev: v16.0.6
    hooks:
        -   id: clang-format
            types_or: [c++, c]

-   repo: meta
    hooks:
    -   id: identity
        types: [python]
```

Comment: and you're sure they're the identical revision and all the dependencies of pre-commit are identical?  no merge is occurring which would adjust that?

Comment: That gave me something to check! Yes, adding a `pip list` to my build script shows both environments where pre-commit is installed to be identical. There are no merges coming into this branch, which is being used solely by me to try to figure this out.

Comment: does it reproduce with newer versions?  3.4.0 at least has a pretty important change if you're hitting OOM

Comment: It reproduces with 3.6.0. I also tried commenting out all hooks *except* black and ruff, but black still says all is well in CI. I can't help but think that the problem will be some dumb, embarrassingly simple thing. I'm just struggling to find it. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: in the repo: what does `git ls-files -z | hd -c` give you?

Comment: Is the idea to get a digest of the file list to compare local to CI? The `hd` output didn't seem helpful, but replacing it with `md5sum` I do get the same values locally and on CI. Maybe I should fork black so I can insert my own debugging code...

Comment: mostly to see if there's something wildly different about the files list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pre-commit.com/#creating-new-hooks), a pre-commit hook "must exit nonzero on failure or modify files." If a hook unexpectedly passes, it should relate to one of those two things.

Using black as an example, it exits with 0 unless the [--check](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#check) flag is passed, even when it reformats files. So pre-commit must be relying on detecting that files had changed to fail the hook.

How does pre-commit know whether files changed? It [uses `git diff`](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/10f8853631ba5cde3040ed4455ef293736157233/pre_commit/commands/run.py#L274) before and after and compares the stdout of the two runs. If they are different, a change must have been made.

Adding the same `git diff` command to my build script, I discovered that it was failing on the CI server and printing an error message. Presumably pre-commit was also getting the error, but the same message before and after, resulting in a "pass" for not detecting a change. It doesn't look like pre-commit checks the exit code of `git diff`.

In my case, `git diff` was failing because of a combination of Bamboo's linked repositories feature and a Docker container not mounting Bamboo's cache directory. The error looked like:

```
error: object directory /opt/bamboo-home/alpha/xml-data/build-dir/_git-repositories-cache/fdae2edae02caea8ea6d761ec2587a93d46f063d/.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
error: unable to find e6ce93b6af518f7e3efd767aa7124aed5d036734
fatal: unable to read e6ce93b6af518f7e3efd767aa7124aed5d036734
```